# Java JPA/Hibernate generates database schema twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I recently tried switching my application from Hibernate's SessionFactory to JPA's EntityManager for a Spring MVC project.

When I run my application with Jetty, the database schema is created twice. (I have the hbm2ddl.auto set to 'create').

More specifically, I see this output twice:

```
INFO: Building JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

**The generated sql by hibernate also shows the exact same SQL statements repeated twice.**

Somehow the entitymanagerfactory is being created twice.

I am using Hibernate version 5.2.9.Final, Spring version 4.3.5.RELEASE

Unfortunately the project does not belong to me, so I do not think I can release code samples. But I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue, and I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in a general direction of where the problem might be.

I have tried switching between `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

I have also switched between using dataSource and persistence.xml

I have also tried filtering `<context:component-scan>` in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to exclude scanning for `@Component` (to avoid potentially having some beans scanned twice), but none of these have worked!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the only reason i would go for a `EntityManagerFactory` over a `SessionFactory` is to use criteria in hibernate 4. In hibernate 5 i don't see any reason to create a `EntityManagerFactory`. and without any configuration/code it will be hard to tell where the mistake is

Comment: We wanted to switch to EntityManager to use JPA callbacks (the PrePersist and PreUpdate annotations). They do not work with hibernate's session factory! But I am considering switching back to session factory and just using hibernate's interceptors / event listeners instead

Comment: Post your `web.xml` and additional configuration files. I suspect you have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet` both loading the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (or the xml wherever your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is defined). Which basically means you already had this issue but it wasn't visible yet.

Comment: I've added the dispatcher-servlet.xml and web.xml

Comment: As stated you are loading your application twice, you already did this when using plain hibernate. Your `ContextLoaderListener` shouldn't load the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` .

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, I just wanted you to know that you were right! I removed dispatcher-servlet.xml from the ContextLoaderListener, but it did not work at first because removing the dispatcher-servlet.xml file from the ContextLoader made some necessary beans unavailable in the global context (such as UserDetailsService for Spring Security). But I just referenced those beans from the spring-security.xml file itself and now everything is working! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: what happens if you run ddlauto = validate?

Comment: If validate is used then no schema is generated. But the underlying problem was, as M. Deinum suggested, that the dispatcher-servlet.xml file was being read in twice. Removing "dispatcher-servlet.xml" from the contextLoaderListener solved the issue for me