# Java Spring, JPA, HSQLDB: schema created twice (rarely)

Tags: jpa, hsqldb

I have a Java/Spring application with JPA/HSQLDB as persistence layer. It's deployed on dozens of computers and normally works fine. But recently there were three occasions where the application would not start (so it's really a rare case and I wasn't able to reproduce it).

In those cases, the database was already filled with data from a previous run. Investigating the problem, the reason why the application did not start was that the schema creation was written twice into the data.script file:

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDBxxx
SET DATABASE GC 0
...
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC...
-- now the same lines come again
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDBxxx
SET DATABASE GC 0
...
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC...
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 2 -- the "2" looks suspicious
...
continues with data insertion etc.
```

After removing the duplicate schema creation from data.script, my application starts working normally again.

Anyone having an idea/pointer where I could continue to look for the problem?

I think it's strange that the additional schema creation was written on top of the data.script file - I'd have assumed that lines are only appended to that file.

Any help would be appreciated.

I already tried to start two instances of my application at the same time to provoke a race condition. Also searched HSQLDB bug tracker and stackoverflow for similar issues. I found this question, but there it was a persistent and not a sporadic problem: [Java JPA/Hibernate generates database schema twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305689/java-jpa-hibernate-generates-database-schema-twice)

Comment: Not sure why you'd think this is a JPA problem - JPA isn't likely touching your data.script directly as it should just issue create table statements via your jdbc driver, the second of which should just fail. Turn on logging to see what is executed on startup, but I suspect you have something else controlling your data.script file.

Comment: I don't think it's an JPA problem. Actually I don't really know where to look for the root of the problem as it doesn't make sense for me. Yes, JPA creates table statements, but then they are duplicated in the data.script (and yes, there's an error when HSQLDB executes it). But as the lines are added on top, it's probably not coming from JPA...